# Как в классах C++ подставлять различные реализации методов на этапе компиляции?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компиляция

Хотелось бы понять, как можно выбирать реализацию некоторого С++ метода, наподобии такого подхода:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo A" << std::endl;
    }   
};

class B {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo B" << std::endl;
    }   
};

template <typename T>
class C : public T {

};

int main () {
    C<A> ca;
    C<B> cb;

    // Можно заметить, что вызов функций происходит напямую - без indirection call оверхеда.
    // Никаких указателей на функции, значения которых будут разыменовываться в райнтайме

    ca.foo();   // call   4011f0 <A::foo()>
    cb.foo();   // call   40121c <B::foo()>

    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос в следующем - может быть есть какой-нибудь способ на месте подставлять конкретные адреса вызова функций, но не используя шаблонных конструкций и/или наследования, при этом имея возмонжость легко переключаться между различными реализациями?

Например, вынести тип, из которого мы хотим извлекать адрес функции, используя псевдоним типа, что-то вроде:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo A" << std::endl;
    }   
};

class B {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo B" << std::endl;
    }   
};

class C {
public:
    using T = B;

    /* Тут и происходит магия, которая выполняет подстановку адреса функции */
};

int main () {
    C cb;
    cb.foo();   // call   40121c <B::foo()>

    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: так как типы методов у разных классов разный - адреса у них не совместимы. Помогает использовать общий базовый класс с виртуальными функциями.

Comment: А просто унаследовать `C` от `B` не вариант? Ведь ваше `using T = B;` все равно невозможно поменять во время выполнения программы. А если надо иметь возможность менять вызов во время выполнения - то просто используйте композицию. Или локальные объекты `A` и `B` — что вам удобнее.

Comment: @Harry В рантейме нет никакой необходимости менять поведение, вопрос как раз в том, чтобы подстановка отработала на этапе компиляции/компоновки

Comment: @AlexGlebe Использование виртуальных функций ничем не будет отличаться от использования указателей на функции - из-за обращения к таблице виртуальных функций. Это как раз тот самый оверхед, которого я стремлюсь избежать. Стремление избежать этого проистекает из того, что функция foo будет вызывать очень часто.

Comment: типы A и B - несовместимы.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Предположим, что мы будем использовать невиртуальное наследование A и B от некоторого класса D. В таком случае появляется решение?

Comment: Явная преждевременная оптимизация...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно просто вызывать нужный метод из базового класса. Плюс проверка на то, что `C` наследуется от нужного типа. Но заметьте, что `C<A,B> != C<B,A>` (Да и вообще все варианты `C<...>` не будут одним и тем же классом), так что при таком стиле рано или поздно появятся сложности.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo B" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename ... Args>
struct C : public Args ... {

    template <typename T> requires std::is_base_of_v<T, C>
    void foo() {
        T::foo();
    }
};

int main() {
    C<A, B> l;
    l.foo<A>();
    l.foo<B>();
}
```

Comment: Выглядит роскошно. Только не возникает ли накладных расходов из-за того, что мы вызываем T::foo()? Получается тоже дополнительный indirection level.

Comment: @НикитаСавиных, В release все это инлайнится (Проверил сейчас). Но это только такой простой вариант. Если что-то будет еще находится в `C::foo`, то фиг его знает. Плюс расходы на виртуальный вызовы тоже очень мизерные. Я не уверен, что вам вообще нужно пока об этом беспокоиться.

Comment: Если ответ вам подходит, то неплохо было бы отблагодарить плюсом и принятием